# построение dom из inputstream

Tags: java

мне надо получить dom документа , который я получаю в виде inputStream
есть ли такая возможность ?
пробовал

```
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder =
   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(strArray1);
```

где `strArray1` это файл получаемый в виде inputstream из бд

выдает ошибку в логе на

```
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(strArray1);
```

> error while parsing protocol: invalid lob locator id (piecewise lob reading)

Comment: Похоже, что у Вас в `strArray1` записан мусор. Сохраните его в файл и посмотрите на содержимое и кодировку файла

Comment: @AntonShchyrov  можете дать направление, как сохранить и октрыть? приложение работает на облаке . в java я полный ноль.....пожалуйста

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11501465/5376639

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а есть другой способ посмотреть содержимое?
нет возможности сохдать файл на облаке...ругается

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/309448/5376639

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ошибка на этой строке: IOUtils.copy(strArray1, writer, "UTF-8");
подключил вот эти библиотеки:import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.StringWriter;
в коде не ругается, но при вызове на сервере дает ошибку

Comment: это выглядит очень сомнительно и редко когда работает, сначала надо ватащить файл из бд, посмотреть на него, преждем парсить.